# Use modified version of package with composer

Tags: git, composer-php

In my project, which involves phpunit testing I am using  [Pseudo](https://github.com/jimbojsb/pseudo) to mock PDO's.

Now, I made some changes in this Pseudo code, to suit my purpose. How can I handle this changes in terms of making sure any other person who will clone my project will be able to use Pseudo with the code modifications I did?

Pseudo is obviously in the `.gitignore` file and I really don't want to get it out of there. what will be the best way to handle this situation? Except pull request.

one thing i guess i should add is that i am using composer in my project.

Comment: If your changes add features / fix bugs, it could maybe be interesting to create a pull request. If not, what exactly are those changes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own repository with composer.

Create a new git repository from the modified version of "Pseudo"

then require it like this in your composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "Donoven/pseudo",
            "version": "0.1.0",
            "source": {
               "url": "git@server.co.uk:Repository.git",
               "type": "git",
               "reference": "0.1.0"
            }
         }
    }],
    "require": {
        "Donoven/pseudo": "0.1.*"
    }
}
```

When users will do a composer install, they will be asked for authentification from the git server if it is needed.

See [the composer documentation about private git repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories)